# How to install P5js on windows?

Tags: p5.js

I have downloaded the p5js file on my windows computer but can't find a way to install it 
Have you installed p5js on your pc if yes then please help me

It's a zip file so I extracted it using Winrar but in the extracted files there is one called MacOSX and i suppose that's for mac users even though I clicked on download for Windows button on the official website

Comment: Take a look at this https://p5js.org/get-started/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

p5js does not require an install. The javascript libraries can be downloaded and accessed locally or can be pulled in from a CDN.

The question mentions the MacOSX folder that is included with the source. You can ignore or even delete this folder. The MacOSX folder contains a _DS_Store file which helps Mac operating systems know how to display folder contents. See the [DS_Store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.DS_Store) wiki article for more info.

[p5js get-started](https://p5js.org/get-started/) has a nice introduction and some minimal examples.

```js
function setup() {

}

function draw() {
  ellipse(50, 50, 80, 80);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

If you downloaded a copy of p5.js the complete HTML of the example could look like this

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script src='p5.js'></script>
    <script>
    function setup(){}
    function draw(){
      ellipse(50,50,80,80);
    }
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

A sketch like the one above can be simply saved with an html extension in the same folder as the p5.js file and opened with a web browser.

One thing to note is that as you write more complex sketches that require resources such as images or data files you may need to host your projects on a server. This is also very simple to do. Get more information on simple web servers here: [local-server](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Local-server)

Answer (score 1):

In order to use P5js include CDN

```
<html>
   <head>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.2/p5.js">
     </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, p5.js is a JavaScript library, so you don't really have to install anything for it to work.

If you're looking for a p5.js editor, I recommend using the [p5.js web editor](https://editor.p5js.org/) which handles everything for you.

Shameless self-promotion: [here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/p5js/editors) is a tutorial on using p5.js in various editors, and [here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/p5js/hello-world) is a tutorial on including the script in an HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

We don’t need to install anything, just use the **CDN**…

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.2/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: I don't get it Can you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: you can directly use it like above which I shared @DevanshGupta also please read this article how it can be used https://p5js.org/get-started/

Comment: @DevanshGupta any confusion.?

Comment: I'm sorry but I have now figured out that p5js is a javascript library not an application but thanks for your kindness please do check out my website link of which I have given in my profile and since you guys seem to be much more experienced let me know how I can improve it

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install anything, as you can use the [web editor](https://editor.p5js.org/) or you can install the [processing editor](https://processing.org/download/) and add p5.js mode, and it will conveniently set up everything for you.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to use an IDE with P5.JS

https://code.visualstudio.com/

after that install the extension

[image: p5.js Vs Code]

and then create a folder and name it what ever you want

then hit CTRL SHIFT P and type

"Create p5.js Project"

then select your folder and click on

Sketch.js

[image: Sketch.js]